# Adding a column whose value is not null by default .

Tags: mysql

I have to add a column whose default value is not null by default to the table after particular column using Alter table.

```
ALTER TABLE tblechecklistrevision ADD COLUMN IWorkFlowOrder INT(10) DEFAULT NOT NULL AFTER fState;
```

When I Execute the query I will get the below error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NOT NULL AFTER fState' at line 1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should remove `DEFAULT`:

```
ALTER TABLE tblechecklistrevision 
    ADD COLUMN IWorkFlowOrder INT(10) NOT NULL AFTER fState;
```

DEFAULT is for setting initial value to new rows where a value for that column isn't specified, when you write `...INT(10) NOT NULL` what you mean is actually that that column can never contain a NULL, not only at initialization time.

Answer (score 12):

If you want the default value not to equal `NULL` (example 0) you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE tblechecklistrevision 
    ADD COLUMN IWorkFlowOrder INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER fState
```